# I have created image tag in JavaScript, but it is not displaying image on web page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am calling this function on add button from my PHTML. On click of add button I want to show image of selected fruit in `<div>`.

```
   function moveoutid()
   {
var sda = document.getElementById('availableFruits');
var len = sda.length;
var sda1 = document.getElementById('orderFruits');

for(var j=0; j<len; j++)
{
    if(sda[j].selected)
    {
        alert(baseUrl+"/img/"+sda.options[j].value+".jpg");
        var img1=document.createElement('img').src=baseUrl+"/img/"+sda.options[j].value+".jpg";

        var di=document.getElementById('d');
        di.appendChild(img1);


        var tmp = sda.options[j].text;
        var tmp1 = sda.options[j].value; 
        sda.remove(j);
        j--;
        var y=document.createElement('option');
        y.text=tmp1;
        try
        {
            sda1.add(y,null);
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
            sda1.add(y);
        }
    }
}

   }
```

In this code I have created `<img>` tag and passing image path to `src`, to show selected image on web page. It is correctly taking path of images but it is not appending `<img>` tag and not displaying image on web page.

Comment: do you have an element with id of 'd'? Your html might help here.

Comment: Try to change `var img1=document.createElement('img').src=baseUrl+"/img/"+sda.options[j].value+".jpg";` to `var img1=document.createElement('img'); img.src=baseUrl+"/img/"+sda.options[j].value+".jpg";`.

Comment: Please share more details. Why is this question tagged with PHP, without any such code? How does the markup of your site look like? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, most likely, in this line:

```
var img1=document.createElement('img').src=baseUrl+"/img/"+sda.options[j].value+".jpg";
```

This creates an element, assigns the `src` property to it and then assigns the value of this `src` property to variable `img1`.  Instead, you should do this in two lines:

```
var img1 = document.createElement('img');
img1.src = baseUrl+"/img/"+sda.options[j].value+".jpg";
```